# Mask entire Vue.js app and it's subdirectories to another pages subdirectory

Tags: vue.js, routes, web-deployment, nuxt.js, masking

I would really appreciate some input in how to solve a masking / subdirectory issue with a SSR. It's also my first freelance gig as a front end developer.

I've built a Vue.js-app with dynamic routes, that is loaded in a Wordpress-page subdirectory.

www.wordpresspage.com/vue-app

Since I preferably want static pages (for SEO and meta tags) I'd like to host it on for example Netlify and generate static pages through ex. Nuxt.js.

Is there a way for me to mask the url so that it also routes the subdirectories?

So that my-page.netlify.com/sub-page can be accessed on www.wordpresspage.com/vue-app/sub-page

The alternative for me is at the moment to run the Vue app as SPA and forget about SEO and Open Graph etc.

OR get node.js running on the Wordpress site and do SSR, but honestly that sounds doesn't sound like it's worth the trouble.

Thanks for your input!
John

Comment: Is router [base](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#base) what you're looking for? Also [publicPath](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#publicpath)